# Conditionally format one cell based on values in a column

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

The user enters a date/time into cell B2. If this matches one of the values in column L I would like to format cell B2 as red, else format cell B2 as green.

[image]

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please format B2 green with standard fill, then apply the following *Use a formula to determine which cells to format*, *Format values where this formula is true:*

```
=match(B2,L:L,0)>0
```

with formatting (red) to suit and Applies to B2.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Excel 2007 onwards:

1. Set cell shading for B2 = Green
2. Select Cell B2 and select the `Conditional Formatting` > `New Rule` menu item
3. `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`
4. In the formula bar, put in `=ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2,$L$6:$L$100,0))`
5. For format, change shading to Red

Obviously change the `$L$6:$L$100` to suit you, but that should do it...

Answer (score 1):

What about breaking this up into two steps.

Try putting a simple formula in `Cell B1`:

`=ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2, L:L, 0))`

This will return a `TRUE` if there's a match and a `FALSE` if there is not a match.  Then make two conditional rules based on `Cell B1`.